# How to Use Attribute for JoltSpecification in Nifi Jolt

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I want to create Jolt Specification in Update Attribute processor and use in JoltTransformer processor as an attribute like below.

[image: nifi Update Attribute Component]

[image]

**I get this error in JoltTransformer:
. "is invalid because of the specification not valid for the selected transformation.** 
Reason being Jolt Specification will set during runtime.

[image]

Thanks for the help!
Ani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NiFi-1.6.0 `JoltTransformJson` processor `not accepting attributes in jolt specification property value`.

We still need to keep **`literal jolt specification`** in property value.

***Example:***
[image]

But Starting from **`NiFi-1.7.0`** JoltTransformJson processor ***will be evaluated using flow file attributes and variable registry***

- we can use `${mapping}` starting from `NiFi-1.7.0`

Comment: Shu, Thank you for your answer, is this true for EvaluateJsonPath processor as well. EvaluateJsonPath does not throw an error but does not evaluate the property.

incoming json: {  "indiv_id": "75008f47-99f5-4eb7-8c0e-cfb6ee550964",
  "first_name": "Ila",
  "last_Name": "Gallegos",
  "Address_1": 188,
  "Address_2": "FlorenceAvenue"
}

This is my expression $.${row_id} for property: hb_row_id
But output is emptyString or just {} (when i put ticks like $.${'row_id'})

Comment: @Ani, Yes, **EvaluateJsonPath** Processor will **`not evaluates flowfile attribute or variable Registry`** (checked in NiFi-1.8) also, we still needs to keep all the properties with literal values in it. i.e. `$.id`..etc.